# My days between dates program bugs out when there is January in the date

Tags: python, date, math

In my program which calculates days between dates bugs out when I try to calculate days from January. Depending on the month, if I use the same day in both dates eg "Jan DD, YYYY" and "Feb DD, YYYY" it'd give me the answer + 18 to 22 days depending on the month. Here are the calculations:

```
def indays(year,monthNum,day): ## year 
    leapyears = get_leapYear() ## monthNumber is "01,02 etc" 

    day_inYear = 365            ## day is day
    years_in_days = 0

    month_in_days = 0            

    for y in range(year): #this right here gets the year, and adds a year for every year in the range

        if y in leapyears:
            day_inYear = 366 ##checks if leapyear from the first function index, if it is, it adds 366 days instead of 365
        else:
            day_inYear = 365

        years_in_days = years_in_days + day_inYear

    for m in range(monthNum): #same thing as year, but months
        month = intLength[m]

        if monthNum == 1: ##sometimes i write a function that works, but forget how it works 2 days later.
            month_in_days = day ##i think if the date is in Jan, instead of getting "31" it just get's the given day.
        else:
            month_in_days = month_in_days + month

    sinceAD = years_in_days + month_in_days + day  #adds them up

    return sinceAD
```

then after that in my final return command, I have a little if statement that won't double the days when I have two January(s) because it would count the date twice

```
T1 = indays(yearX,monthNumX,daysX) #just for a value of life, see the if statment 
    T2 = indays(yearY,monthNumY,daysY)

    if T1 > T2: ##so answer isnt negative, checks which total days of date from zero is bigger, and it's y
        y = T1
        x = T2
    else:
        y = T2
        x = T1

    diff = (y - x)

    if monthNumX == 1 or monthNumY == 1:
        diff = diff - abs(daysX-daysY)
    else:
        pass

    return diff
```

I mean this is more of a math question than a programming question, but I'm super lost.

Comment: what does intLength[m] hold. Is intLength[0]=31 and IntLength[1]=28 (and 29 in a leap year?). It feels like the way it is written now, a January date has day added in twice.

Comment: Or I see where you try to fix that, but it would be cleaner when monthNum is 1 to just set month_in_days to 0

Comment: Yeah, that's better than what I did. It's not going to fix it though is it?

Comment: @JeremyKahan ..

Comment: I do not think so. I would suggest doing some sanity checks on just a date at a time. So like what does it think January 1,in the 7th year of the common era was?My hunch is the way to go is to be sure it is behaving nicely with one date, because with two it gets harder to debug, since mostly accumulated errors cancel out, except when they don't. It also feels like January should not be such a special case, since you never want to add all the days in the very last month.

Comment: I suggest that you rethink the math on this before writing code.  Your loop `for m in range(monthNum):` loops with values from 0 to monthNum-1, which looks wrong.  The day number of the current year (1-365/366) is the day of the month plus the sum of days in the preceding months of the year.  It looks like you should be looping on `range(1,monthNum)` instead.  You also don't need an if statement in that loop.

Comment: Along those lines, like @MikeHousky says, start a little smaller, Write a function that calculates a julian date (number between 1 and 366, days since January 1 this year, plus 1) given a month day and year. Test it for days in January, February, March, and December 31 both in and and out of leap year. Once you have that working, you can add in complete years before the year of the date given. If that all works, then the difference should not require anything fancy to correct it, save for the absolute value.

Comment: I think you want in range(year-1) and range(monthnum-1), and the latter gets rid of your need for an if monthNum ==1. The idea would be not to add for the current year or month, which is not complete.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer, but what is below is better. Still, to understand where your logic was off, the key issue was that years, days, and months start at 1, and by default, ranges start at 0. If you wanted to stick with that, you needed for y in range(year-1) and  for m in range(monthNum-1), then to look at y+1 and m+1. That with my previous comment about removing the if, makes your code work.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Starting my months at zero would definitely make more sense.. I'll update my program and check.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loop over 2000+ year numbers to count days, a little math will save lots of code and time.  What follows assumes the Gregorian calendar and it's rules for leap years.

An absolute day number is any integer value that increases by 1 each calendar day.  For a days-between-dates calculation, it doesn't matter what the value is for a particular date.  Only differences will be used.  For convenience, I'll pick a starting value where day 1 is 01-Jan-0001.

In any given year, the absolute day number is the day of the current year (1-366) plus the number of days in preceding years.  Finding the number of days in preceding years can be done without a loop.

Assuming input variables name `mm, dd, yyyy` for month(1-12), day(1-31) and 4-digit year number, the number of days in preceding years is:
    days_before_jan1 = (yyyy - 1)*365 # 365 ordinary days per year
    days_before_jan1 += (yyyy - 1)//4 # add 1 leap day every 4 years
    days_before_jan1 -= (yyyy - 1)//100 # remove "even century" days
    days_before_jan1 += (yyyy - 1)//400 # put back multiples of 400

That's written for exposition.  In real code, I'd put all 4 terms in a single expression `t*365 + t//4 - t//100 - t//400` after setting `t` to `yyyy-1`.

For days in the month, you could build a list:

```
mdays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
if isleap(yyyy): mdays[1] = 29
```

That's got the number of days for each month of the `yyyy` year, assuming you have defined an `isleap` function to return `True` if given a leap year.  You can use that either in a loop:

```
pm_days = 0 # days in preceding months
for m in range(1,mm): # loop through all preceding months this year
    pm_days += mdays[m-1]
```

Or you could simply slice out and sum the days with:
    pm_days = sum(mdays[:mm])

Now add up `days_before_jan1 + pm_days + dd` and you have your absolute day number.

**NOTE: Be sure to use // for integer division in Python. It's optional in Python 2, but necessary in Python 3.**